# Image for border-bottom

Tags: css

I have a navigation menu with css style of border-bottom and border top set to 2px. This gives a fairly plain look. I want to use an image instead of a line. I have tried to use the src option for this but no luck.

my codde:

`border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF; border-top: 2px solid #FFF;`

Any help would be appreciated.
Gus

Comment: Can you add your HTML too? so we might help?

Comment: @gussy81, you want to use an image instead of *which* line? Top or bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `border-image` property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Note that it's only compatible with newer browsers (read no IE), so leave your normal border declaration in as a fallback.